# Hyperscale Vs Strong-scale HPC

Tags: gpu

NVIDIA's Tesla GPUs for Servers includes market segments called `"Hyperscale HPC"` and `"Strong-Scale HPC"`. How different is `"Strong-Scale"`*ing*  from  `"Hyperscale"`*ing* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are both marketing words. Either ask NVIDIA what they mean by them, or ignore them. NVIDIA appears to be using them to classify different product lines, at either different cost levels or different levels of parallelism. You can almost certainly ignore these marketing terms safely. They have no definite meaning to me.

Comment: I agree, one would want to look at your requirements vs hardware capabilities and ignore buzz words. I first saw the new buzz word "hyperscale" used by the trade press, not NVIDIA, in connection with cloud computing. The way I interpret it, using Seymour Cray's famous analogy: Strong-scaling: two strong oxen, hyper-scaling: 1024 chickens.